# Checking dynamically built radio button list with jQuery

Tags: jquery, papaparse

I'm trying to use jQuery to grab the value of a selected radio button.  If I build a simple static page, it works fine.  [Simple working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnyaya/f3yyhpd2/)

However, when I build the radio list dynamically, using PapaParse to parse a simple string and jQuery to build the list, it no longer works.  [Dynamic not working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/johnyaya/L9L61dub/)

Here's the function I'm using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("input:radio[name=xAxisSelector]").on("change", function() {
      if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        // do stuff
        alert(this.checked)
        alert(this.value)
      }
    });
});
```

Clearly I'm missing something, and it's probably something simple, but I'm completely stumped.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery used to have LIVE available for this, but it doesn't any longer.

change

```
$("input:radio[name=xAxisSelector]").on("change", function() {
```

to

```
 $(document).on("change","input:radio[name=xAxisSelector]", function() {
```

Answer (score 1):

Its just the order of events, you are building radio buttons parallel while binding events. Change it to be sequential. Here is the updated [sample](https://jsfiddle.net/L9L61dub/1/)

```
function bindEvents(){
$("input:radio[name=xAxisSelector]").on("change", function() {
      if (jQuery(this).is(":checked")) {
        // do stuff
        alert(this.checked)
        alert(this.value)
      }
    });
}

     $(document).ready(function(){
        parseString();
        bindEvents();
    });
```